# How to get AdMob on RoboVm

Tags: libgdx, admob, robovm

I'm using libGDX and i haven't found any tutorial related to AdMob on RoboVM. I have all the bindings but I'm not sure whether to add the admob folder as a referenced library or just in the build path. Also I don't know how to get a banner ad in the app. Anyone know how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see related answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22031703/2399024

Answer (score 0):

You can use Androids banners from AdMob if you bind your AdMob through MoPub.

Check out MoPub here: http://www.mopub.com/